# Unix - server gets polluted - find out were new files get stored

Tags: unix, filesystems

My server has no available space left on disk. Yesterday, I deleted 200 GB Data, today it is full again. Some Process must write some files. How do I find out where possibly new huge files are stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `df` to check partition usage.
Use `du` to find sizes of folders.
I tend to do this:

```
du -sm /mount/point/* | sort -n
```

This gives you a list with the size of folders in MB in the `/mount/point` folder.

Also if you have `X` you can use `baobab` or similar utilies to explore disk usage.

PS: check the log files. For example if you have `Tomcat` installed it tends to generate crazy amount of log if not configured properly.